# How can I make this typo effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, typography

[image]

want to make a work with distortion in photoshop or illustrator.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to GDSE. In Illustrator you can convert text to outlines, and edit the paths. Try that.

Comment: athese kinds of questions are hard to answer. Not because doing this is hard, but rather what the unsaid part is. There is nothing said about what you know how to do and what not. Theres also nothing said about workflow or what its for. Any answer i would give you would essentially either exceed your comprehension or teach really babysteps that might sound patronizing.

Answer (score 2):

I am following what Billy Kerr said. Just added one step, which is I creat some shapes to cut out. Thank you.

[image]